# python csv avoid double quote

Tags: python, mysql-python

I am using the code below to convert the mysql table values to a csv file. Everything is working fine but it's adding double quotes for few values; you can see this in the fourth field of the example.

```
import MySQLdb
import csv
conn = MySQLdb.connect(user='root',  db='users', host='localhost')
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM users.newusers')
ver = cursor.fetchall()
#print ver
csv_file = open('filename', 'w')
writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
writer.writerows(ver)
csv_file.close()
```

The output that I am getting:

```
115,New,918097678052,"Rajendran, Mohan",rajemohn,National,#N.A,No,No,No,#N.A,OS40,005056BB0803,192.168.10.10,no,yes
```

The output that I require:

```
115,New,918097678052,Rajendran Mohan,rajemohn,National,#N.A,No,No,No,#N.A,OS40,005056BB0803,192.168.10.10,no,yes
```

Comment: Before writing, replace comma by empty string.

Comment: `"Rajendran, Mohan"` is correct, that is a single value/column no? Your data obviously comes as a single string  like `'Rajendran, Mohan'` and it is correctly written as such, how is the csv lib supposed to know you want to remove the comma between the name?

Comment: `import sys
file = open('newrequest.csv')
for line in file:
    fields = line.strip().split(",")#    print fields[2]
    ext = fields[2]
   print ext
    wiw = fields[4].upper()
    print wiw
    dname = fields[3]
   print dname
`                                                                                                        i am using the above code to read the csv but third value is partial